# SSH password problem

Tags: networking, ssh, password, client

I have connected two machines via Ethernet cable, 192.168.1.2(master) & 192.168.1.3(slave). I can ssh both and even ping command also works fine. Trouble is while running Hadoop & Nutch I have to ssh to the other machine, comes a part where ssh asks for password like this:

`root@192.168.1.2 password: root@192.168.1.3 password`

Wonder whose password should I be giving? master's? or slave's? or should it be:

`master's passwd: slave passwd`?.

Comment: What command do you run? You might want to set up ssh to use certificates to log in instead of ordinary username/password. It's convenient but I don't think it's your problem here. But hard to know without knowing what command you run.

Answer (score 1):

The machine you ssh from is typically called the client. The server you connect to is called the server.

You would use the (root) password you use to log into the server.

Note: In general you should try to avoid ssh as root, ssh in as a user and use sudo if at all possible.

Comment: @bodi.zazen yeah thanks for that, i was wondering what should i put in when it asks me in the terminal like this : "root@192.168.1.2 password :root@192.168.1.3 password" should i give root at 192.168.1.2's paswrd or root @ 192.168.1.3's paswrd or should i put it in this format "root@192.168.1.2's pswrd: root@192.168.1.3's pswrd"

Comment: You should not use sudo on the first ssh. You do not need to be root to run ssh on the first machine you connect from. And no, you can't be shore to which sudo your character is sent.